# how to access column value after serialization activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a simple model like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :preferences
end
```

I want to access the raw value from mysql, not value before serialize. Is it possible?

I know I can use

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select * from users")
```

But I want to access from the `User` model.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Updated**

Ok, this is what you are looking for:

```
User.find(params[:id]).attributes_before_type_cast["preferences"][:value]
```

This will return the string in its serialized form.

That is the closest you can get that I can find, it won't work if you have already gotten the object pulled from the database.

Sorry for misreading your question.  You can use this from the User model too.

Leaving the old answer up just in case the other way of doing it is helpful to someone.

**Old Answer**

Just to be sure I understand the question, you want the raw data from the table.  The data that rails serializes and puts in the database.

EX. You put in `['site_id','last_update','last_restart']` and you get `"---\n- site_id\n- last_update\n- last_restart\n"` and it is put in the database and saved.  You want to retrieve this: `"---\n- site_id\n- last_update\n- last_restart\n"` from the database.

Ok, it took some fanagaling from the database but you can do it like so.

In a project I have a serialized array call `devise_table_preferences` that lists the preferences to display in a table in a particular order, like so:

```
user.devise_table_preferences = ['site_id','last_update','last_restart']
```

The serialized view of it is like so:

```
"---\n- site_id\n- last_update\n- last_restart\n"
```

Using your method above, I made a query like so:

```
preference = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT devise_table_preferences FROM users WHERE id = #{@user.id}")
```

It returns an object in the console like so:

```
preference = #<Mysql2::Result:0x007fe4cdf34850>
```

Running:

```
preference.first[0]
```

Gave me this:

```
"---\n- site_id\n- last_restart\n"
```

I know its a big work around but it will definitely give you your data in its serialized way.  Hope that it helps you out.

Comment: I know i can do that (as i said in the question). I just want to know it is possible to get from the User model or not. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: @Chamnap I edited my answer to hopefully answer your question, see updated part of the answer.  Hope that helps you more than the older part did.

Comment: I try it, but it doesn't work. I checked the source code, it's simply return the `@attributes` back, that one is already serialized.

Comment: @Chamnap, Hm... This should work for you.  It works for me in the console and I have the same setup as you.  Running `User.first.attributes_before_type_cast["netbridge_table_preference"][:value]` in my Rails Console gave me: `=> "---\n- site_id\n- last_restart\n"` instead of `['site_id','last_restart']`. To verify, that is what you want right? You want it serialized, not deserialized and turned back into an array, hash, etc.  I am running rails 3.2.3 and Ruby 1.9.3p194 and getting it back perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, I want it serialized (the value that get saved into db). Sorry to confuse you. :) I found the problem why it doesn't work for me. It's because I just save that record, so the value is unserialized (ruby array). I need to call `reload` so that I can get the serialized value.

Comment: Ok, perfect. Glad that I was able to help.

Comment: Pretty sure this no longer works, as serialization overrides `attributes_before_type_cast`

Answer (score 2):

attributes_before_type_cast didn't work for me.

```
User.first.instance_variable_get(:@attributes)['preferences'].serialized_value
```

This works even if the object is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think these days you want to say the following:

> User.find(params[:id]).typecasted_attribute_value('preferences')

Comment: `NoMethodError Exception: private method 'typecasted_attribute_value' called` (Rails 4.2). Maybe its access changed recently.

Comment: You should use `preferences_before_type_cast` in Rails 4